# Loading all vector layers which are in different folders

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

How can I load, with the graphical modeler of QGIS, all point layers in one shot (called in the same way 'a') which are in different folders, and all linear layers (called in the same way 'b') also these in different folders.
All these different folders are in the same folder.

What kind of input should I use?

Comment: You want to add them to the map using modeler? What kind of file format is it?

Comment: yes, i want to add them to the map in one shot using modeler. They are shapefiles.

Comment: I can show you how to add the layers to the map using python, if that is an option for you? I dont know if it is possible with modeler. Can you add a screenshot showing some example layers in the file explorer?

Comment: Yes, it could be an alternative using python...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this using pyqgis. If you have many shapefiles, you might want uncheck "Render" first.

```py
import os

shapefolder = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/LMV-data_2021-10/' #This folder and all subfolders in it will be searched for files
searchstring = 'by' #Find files with this string in the name

layers = [] #A list to hold the matching layers
for root, folder, files in os.walk(shapefolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp') and searchstring in file:
            #file is now the filename, for example by_riks.shp
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            #fullname is full path to the file, /home/bera/GIS/Data/LMV-data_2021-10/tk_riks_Sweref_99_TM_shape/terrang/riks/by_riks.shp
            layers.append(QgsVectorLayer(fullname, file.split('.')[0])) #Create a layer, name it like the filename without .shp, append to layers list
            
#layers list is now: [<QgsVectorLayer: 'by_riks' (ogr)>, <QgsVectorLayer: 'by_riks' (ogr)>]
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers) #Add the layers to the map
```

[image]